# como obtener el nombre de las inicializaciones de clases hijas?

Tags: java, poo, herencia

este codigo  imprime  como texto "peliculaDemiedo" "PeliculaAnimada"..que son instancias de la clase Main

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Main{

    public String pelicualaDeMiedo=new String("chucky");
    public String pelicualaAnimada=new String("Balto");
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Main t=new Main();
       for(Field p:t.getClass().getFields()){
       System.out.println(p.getName());
     }
  }
}
```

lo que busco es similar imprimir las  instancias pero esta vez de clases hijas

```
FanMasacre fanMasacre3=new FanMasacre ("Carla","Flores","45223666",16,30); 
Televidente televidente1=new Televidente("Pedro","Ruiz","75184023",24,50);
```

busco obtener "fanMasacre3" "televidente1"

Answer (score 1):

La idea es lo mismo debido a que `Class.getFields()` devuelve una arreglo que contiene los `Objetos` que refleja todos los campos públicos accesibles de la clase

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Main{

    public String pelicualaDeMiedo=new String("chucky");
    public String pelicualaAnimada=new String("Balto");
    public static FanMasacre fanMasacre3= new FanMasacre ("Carla","Flores","45223666",16,30); 
    public static Televidente televidente1=new Televidente("Pedro","Ruiz","75184023",24,50);
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Main t=new Main();        
       for(Field p:t.getClass().getFields()){
            System.out.println(p.getName());
        }
  }
}
```

La salida será

```
pelicualaDeMiedo
pelicualaAnimada
fanMasacre3
televidente1
```